# Namelookup issue on Azure using custom Docker container

Tags: linux, php, linux-networking, docker, azure-web-apps

I'm having trouble with name resolution on Azure using custom Docker container with Web App on Linux.

Name resolution with curl and wget takes 4-10 seconds when using default resolv.conf file in Azure.

```
search reddog.microsoft.com
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options timeout:1 attempts:5 ndots:0
```

When i change nameserver to 8.8.8.8, all works fine.

If i understand correctly, [Docker mounts the host machine's resolv.conf file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns) and DNS settings should be set with Docker run command options. It's not recommended to change these files directly.

> The exact details of how Docker manages the DNS configurations inside
>   the container can change from one Docker version to the next. So you
>   should not assume the way the files such as /etc/hosts,
>   /etc/resolv.conf are managed inside the containers and leave the files
>   alone and use the following Docker options instead.

However, it doesn't seem possible to set docker run parameters in Azure.

This is my [previous post on this subject on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155659/curl-error-28-resolving-timed-out-on-wordpress-on-azure-app-service-on-linux).